# Copiar .ssh directory dentro container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Intento copiar los ficheros de ssh key de mi usuario a un contenedor de docker. En mi contenedor de docker tengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero copiar de mi directorio `~/.ssh` todos los ficheros a directorio del contenedor `/root/.ssh`

Uso el siguiente comando:

```
docker cp ~/.ssh/. apiphp:/root/.ssh/
```

El proceso se ejecuta y recibo un *Successfully copied* pero veo que los ficheros no se copian...

Con el mismo comando, cambiando a otro directorio, la copia es correcta.

¿A qué se puede deber? Entiendo que tiene algo que ver con que el directorio esté como `MOUNT`.
¿Podría ser por eso? ¿Alguna solución?